# Unable to play youtube video in android tv from my app - "service version update required"

Tags: android, youtube, android-tv, android-youtube-api

When i try to access youtube video from my app youtube video view in android tv , youtube app is showing an error - "service version update required". What will be the issue? In mobile devices and tablet, app is playing properly. I'm getting error in Android TV alone.

Comment: Is the TV a smart TV or a real Android TV? The reason I ask is, I was unfortunate of having a smart TV from Sony. They brand it as an Android TV, but I am limited to their app store and had a similar experience. And the sad part is, I couldn't do anything about it.

Comment: Hi, Mine is an Android smart TV of TCL. Normal youtube videos are playing, but when i try to play youtube video through my app, the video is not playing.

Comment: Try maybe this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J6dNXQwGpzs or maybe this link https://www.support.com/how-to/how-to-fix-software-update-issues-on-a-tcl-smart-tv-10862